# Is there a format string for SimpleDateFormat to get milliseconds date-time value instead of human-readable form?

Tags: java, string, datetime, formatting, datetime-format

By means of classes like SimpleDateFormat it is possible to format time and date in a suitable format.

Examples here

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#examples

In Java it starts with milliseconds value and then that value gets translated into human readable format.

Sometime it is useful to have that value instead of the human readable form.

Example:

If I am not wrong the 1578738100000 value just means the UTC value Sat Jan 11 2020 10:21:40.

Is it possible to have a format string that yields a string with milliseconds instead of the human readable form?

I know that it is possible to get the milliseconds value directly from the Date class but what I am asking here is whether milliseconds are one of the possible format string to feed SimpleDateFormat (or similar classes) with.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be clear in understanding that date-time value objects and formatter objects play different roles.

- A date-time object has no format, it represents a date and/or time-of-day with or without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.
- A formatter has no value, no date nor time-of-day. A formatter’s job is to work with a date-time object to produce text in a certain format representing that date-time object’s value.

So tracking a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference is the job of the date-time object, not the formatter. Producing human-readable text is the job of the formatter. So, no, the formatter does not produce a count of milliseconds.

And, no, you should not be using a count of milliseconds to communicate date-time values. Such numbers have no meaning to a human reader which leads to easily missing erroneous data. And such data does not readily identify itself - is it a number of whole seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds? And what is the epoch reference date, which of the [couple dozen commonly used epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing)?

Instead communicate date-time values as text using the ISO 8601 standard formats.

Another problem: you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

If your number is a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, parse as a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_578_738_100_000L ) ;
```

If you insist on working with a count-from-epoch against my advice, you can interrogate the `Instant`.

```
long milliseconds = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

For other formats, adjust the `Instant` into an `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` object, and generate text with a `DateTimeFormatter`. All this has been covered many many times already. So search Stack Overflow to learn more.

```
instant
.atZone( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
    .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )
)
```

Lastly, be aware that while the legacy classes were limited to a resolution of milliseconds, the *java.time* classes revolve to the much finer nanoseconds. So beware of possible data loss when calling `Instant::toEpochMilli` as any microseconds or nanoseconds are ignored,

Answer (score 0):

The old and outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class cannot do that. Its replacement, the modern `DateTimeFormatter`, can.

```
    DateTimeFormatter epochMilliFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
            .toFormatter();

    Instant sampleInstant = OffsetDateTime
            .of(2020, 1, 11, 10, 21, 40, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant();

    String formattedValue = epochMilliFormatter.format(sampleInstant);
    System.out.println(formattedValue);
```

Output from this snippet is the number you mentioned:

> 1578738100000

Using `ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS` in the formatter gives us the *seconds* since the epoch. We wanted *milliseconds*, so we need to append `ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND` immediately and make sure that they are printed in exact 3 positions, zero padded. This is what the `3` as 2nd argument to `appendValue()` does.

> Is it possible to have *a format string* that yields a string with
>   milliseconds …?

No, with a format pattern string it is not possible, neither with `SimpleDateFormat` nor with `DateTimeFormatter`. You can go through the possible pattern letter of each and see that there is no pattern letter for neither seconds nor milliseconds since the epoch.

**Are you sure that you want it, though?** Even if this is for storing or for data interchange between systems, using milliseoncds since the epoch is not generally recommended exactly because they not human readable and therefore troublesome in debugging and in ad hoc queries. For most purposes you will be better off using a string in ISO 8601 format, like `2020-01-11T10:21:40Z`. See the other answer by Basil Bourque for details. ISO 8601 format has been designed to be readable by both humans and computers.

### You should not have wanted to use SimpleDateFormat anyway

The `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome (though even more for parsing than for formatting). It is also long outdated. The `Date` class that you mentioned is poorly designed and long outdated too. I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as I do above.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with the format pattern letters that it accepts.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about using a format string, not getting the milliseconds. This is similar but does not use a format string, if I am not wrong..

Comment: No, that is not possible. Please see my edit. @P5music I am letting my answer stand if only for other readers.